# How do I change and select which Polygon thermal relief Altium Designer 19 shall use?

Tags: altium, polygon

How can I make a polygon in a Signal layer in Altium Desginer 19, to change its copper thermal relief?

I've created a rule for it, or so I think.

[image]

But I have not been able to find where I select which rule the Polygon shall follow.
In my case I want the blue marked areas to be filled, without thermal relief.
[image: ![enter image description here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the easiest way is to set up a custom query rule using IsNamedPolygon as follows:
[image]
This uses Direct connect on polygons named 'PolygonDirect'. So all you have to do is name the polygons you want to have direct connection 'PolygonDirect'.
[image]